# Sorting an array of Strings with a numeric value, java

Tags: java, string, sorting, arraylist, double

I have a program that calculates the correlation value between a currency and a stock value. I'm adding the "pairs" (currency name + ": " + Correlation Value) in to an ArrayList and if i print out the arraylist this is my output:

```
SDG: 0.6672481089755959
RON: 0.7950474904606127
MKD: 0.788195252851783
MXN: 0.8429550156320716
CAD: 0.7777753208834005
ZAR: 0.8254509631193871
```

I'm trying to think of a smart way to sort them by correlation value, from biggest to smallest, but can't think of a good way of doing this. Any ideas?

Comment: `Double` implements `Comparable` interface. So, you can sort using `Collections.sort(List<Double>)`

Comment: You obviously need a special class enclosing currency as enum (or string) and correlation value as double. Then sort by this value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have three approaches:

1. Use `Collections.sort` with a custom comparator, which splits the string by `:` (and trims it) and then returns the `.compareTo` value of the numeric part of your string.
2. Create a new object maybe call it `CurrencyCorrelation` which has 2 properties (`currencyName` and `correlation` maybe?). The class will implement the `Comparable` interface and override the `toString()` method to yield the correlation as you'd like (`currencyName + ": " + String.valueOf(correlation)`). You would then call `Collections.sort(...)` without the need of specifying the comparator, as per option 1.
3. As per @Sasha Salauyou's recommendation, you could also declare the class, as per option 2 and then use Java 8 lamba expressions to define the comaparator, without the need of having your class extend the `Comparable` interface. This would look something like so: `list.sort((e1, e2) -> e1.getCorrelation().compareTo(e2.getCorrelation()))`

The second option would probably be better, with the first option requiring less changes.

Comment: The inconveniences from encoding the information in a String will tend to accumulate. The second option will result in a simpler, more maintainable, program.

Comment: Having enclosing class, OP will be able to sort just by `list.sort((e1, e2) -> e1.cor.compareTo(e2.cor))`

Comment: @SashaSalauyou: Thanks for your comment. I have updated my answer to include your recommendation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, ill have to try and implement this. May i ask why the downvotes though, is the question too broad?

Comment: @AntonHeikinheimo: A good question usually includes what the problem is, what you are getting and what you are expecting. In your case, you state what you have and what you would like to end up with, but do not show any effort in trying to solve the problem for yourself. In the future, please keep this in mind. (Please refrain from dumping your entire code though, a small example showing what the problem is, is usually enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could store them in a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) which is already sorted. From Docs:

*The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.*

Comment: here he want to sort one the basis of value not key.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your elements are strings and that the correlation values are doubles, you can simply write your own comparator and sort:

```
Collections.sort(al, new Comparator<String>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {

        double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1.substring(s1.indexOf(": ") + 2));
        double d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2.substring(s2.indexOf(": ") + 2));

        return Double.compare(d1, d2);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/** Immutable class holding currency-correlation pair */
public static class CurrencyCor {

    public final String currency;
    public final Double correlation;

    private CurrencyCor(String cur, Double cor) {
        if (cur == null || cor == null) 
            throw new NullPointerException("Null argument(s)");
        currency = cur;
        correlation = cor;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
         return String.format("%s: %s", currency, correlation)
    }
}

// ...

List<CurrencyCor> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new CurrencyCor("SDG", 0.6672481089755959));
list.add(new CurrencyCor("ZAR", 0.8254509631193871));
// ... add remaining pairs

list.sort((e1, e2) -> e1.correlation.compareTo(e2.correlation)); // sort by correlation value
list.forEach(System.out::println);   // print out sorted pairs
```

Comment: @Albert Java 8 was released more than a year ago. I believe it should be treated as default nowadays.